# error message inside text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am working on Login page where I want my error on inside the input tag

Right now I am getting error in the top of the login panel.

Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validate({
        debug: false,
        errorClass: "error error_red",
        rules: {
            username: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            username: "Please enter a valid email address",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            // This handler will show only one error at time - the first in this instance // 
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            //alert("error" + errors);
            if (errors) {
                $("#errbox").html(validator.errorList[0].message);
                $("#errbox").show();
                validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
            } else {
                $("#errbox").hide();
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            // Override error placement to not show error messages beside elements //
        },
    });
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bjkup35a/1/)

Regards
Mahadevan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the placeholder attribute in the input to set the error message:

```
$('#myInput').attr("placeholder", "This input has an error");
```

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f72jq9uj/) that shows it working.